# Thymeleaf + Spring multiple item selection

Tags: html, spring, controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to get multiple string value into an array via Spring + Thymeleaf like below. However, the string array always returns null. Is there anything I am missing out ?

Related HTML code;

```
...
    <select multiple="multiple"
       name="selected_nodes[]" class="form-control multi-select">
       <option th:each="node : ${nodes}" th:value="${node.id}"
          th:text="${node.name}"
          th:selected="${node.target_id} == ${target.id}"></option>
    </select>
...
```

Related Controller code;

```
    ...

   String[] selected_nodes = request.getParameterValues("selected_nodes");

    ...
```

selected_nodes always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve that by just remove the brackets at name field;

```
...
    <select multiple="multiple"
       name="selected_nodes" class="form-control multi-select">
       <option th:each="node : ${nodes}" th:value="${node.id}"
          th:text="${node.name}"
          th:selected="${node.target_id} == ${target.id}"></option>
    </select>
...
```

name = "selected_nodes"

instead of

name = "selected_nodes[]"